# Mounting ntfs on startup gives errors

Tags: mount, kubuntu, ntfs

I have a NTFS Partition that I want to be mounted on every startup. Currently Kubuntu tells me on every startup `There have been errors checking the filesystem`
and then stops the boot process until I told it to ingore or skip or manually recover from the errors. If I press skip the partition gets mounted and everything seems to work fine.

If I mount that same partition with `sudo mount /media/Windows_Data` after startup I get no errors whatsoever.

The corresponding part of the fstab file:

```
UUID=F444E6DC44E6A09A   /media/Windows_Data     ntfs    defaults,users,auto     0       2
```

This is what /var/log/boot.log has to say to this:

```
/boot.log:mountall: fsck /media/Windows_Data [424] brach mit dem Status 8 ab
/boot.log:mountall: Nicht behebbarer fsck-Fehler: /media/Windows_Data
/boot.log:Fehler auf /media/Windows_Data werden auf Anfrage des Benutzers ignoriert
```

Unfortunately thats in german so I will try to translate that

```
/boot.log:mountall: fsck /media/Windows_Data [424] stopped with status 8
/boot.log:mountall: Not recoverable fsck-Error: /media/Windows_Data
/boot.log:Errors on /media/Windows_Data will be ignored due to user request.
```

Any ideas what I can try to get this error fixed?

Comment: you should also have a look at `fsck.ntfs`, see [this page on super-user](http://superuser.com/questions/233700/fsck-an-ntfs-drive-in-linux)

Comment: I ran `fsck.ntfs`, but it didn't find any errors and did not correct this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Ubuntu 12.04 seems to have fixed this.

The boot process doesn't get interrupted by mount errors any more and the partition is mounted after login and seems to work fine.

There seem to be no errors concerning this partition in /var/log/ as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to run a check disk on your windows partition; in Windows. You can do this by running the program `CHKDSK` on your Windows Operating System. You will encounter this error possibly every time you don't properly shutdown Windows; don't you **love** NFTS file-systems?

If for some reason you have possibly encrypted your partition, that would provide errors as well; but that is really abnormal.

Comment: I tried running the Windows disk checking through the GUI menu that you get when right clicking the partition and selecting properties, but that didn't fix this issue. I will try the `CHKDSK` utility the next time I boot into windows.

Comment: There is a method to force it during startup, have you tried this?

Comment: no, but it got unmounted right away and then checked it for like an hour or so. It is not my primary windows partition, just a data partition that i use to share stuff between windows and linux.